# OSX — open program in a background Space?

Tags: macos, osx-spaces

In Spaces for OSX, is it possible to open a program in a background Space without having to switch to that Space beforehand, whether natively (unlikely) or through some sort of script or external program?

I often want to load an application in a Space other than the one I'm currently working in, and it would be convenient if I didn't have to switch to that Space first. (Unfortunately, this is exactly what the "Application Assignments" option in the Spaces preferences does.) In addition, even if I start an application in one Space and then switch to another, the application opens its windows in my current Space upon initialization, not the one in which it was started. It would be great if those windows could be opened in the background of its starting Space, so that I didn't have to move them over manually.

Thanks!